# Bootstrap3 @media for a class within a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This works for h1 but does not work for the p within jumbtron and I can't work out why. If I resize the browser so its smaller than 500 h1 changes to 15px but p does not and stays at 10px?

```
 @media(min-width:500px) 
{ 
 .jumbotron h1{
      font-size: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;}

 .jumbotron p{
      font-size: 20px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;}
}
```

and

```
.jumbotron h1 {font-size: 15px;}


.jumbotron p {font-size: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have the @media inside of the h1, you should have it as...

```
@media screen and (width 500px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

@media should always be placed outside of everything else and then all attributes which need to be changed at certain widths or heights should be placed inside. Also, it's not Bootstrap specific, it is in face a new CSS3 attribute. Check out [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) for a more in depth explanation and for a better understanding.

Comment: Awesome thank you! However I have done that, it works fine for h1 however p does not work. It stays one size the whole time where as h1 changes?

Comment: In your @media, you have targeted the p tag as .jumbotron p which takes higher precedence than your normal p tag. Change the normal p tag to .jumbotron p and it will work.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence to understand CSS precedence.

Comment: I have change them both so they are .jumbotron p inside the @media and outside it but now the p is set to 10px regardless of size and does not apply the @ media to it?

Comment: Hmm then I would try changing them both to just a p and if that doesn't work then you need to get firebug and right click the p tag which should be changing. It should then give you an indication of why it's not changing.

Comment: Thank you! This is so strange, I used firebug and the font-size that should be applied when its width is bigger 500px is crossed out and it applies the font-size defined outside of the @media which is 10px however it does apply the margin-bottom: 20px but just not the font size. Really don't understand this :(

Comment: It now works as I have placed the @media after the standard css rather than before it. Still confused why having it that way round worked for h1 and not for p, surely if it was because of the order then both should have not worked, thank you for your help though!